# What is the default sort algorithm in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a data table pushing data to Crystal reports.  We noticed seemingly inconsistent sorting and assumed it was bankers rounding, round to even, odd, or something similar.  It doesn't seem to follow that pattern.  This isn't a complete set of data but here are examples of how the rounding is working.  Does anyone know what this pattern is?  We need to be able to test against it reliably.  I should note that X always rounds to Z so it's consistent.

Thanks

```
 
0.45 --- 0.4
3.45 --- 3.5
6.45 --- 6.5
9.45 --- 9.4
12.45 --- 12.5
15.45 --- 15.5
18.45 --- 18.5
21.45 --- 21.5
24.45 --- 24.5
27.45 --- 27.5
30.45 --- 30.5
33.45 --- 33.4
36.45 --- 36.4
39.45 --- 39.4
42.45 --- 42.5
45.45 --- 45.5
48.45 --- 48.5
51.45 --- 51.5
54.45 --- 54.5
57.45 --- 57.5
60.45 --- 60.5
63.45 --- 63.5
66.45 --- 66.5
69.45 --- 69.5
72.45 --- 72.5
75.45 --- 75.5
78.45 --- 78.5
81.45 --- 81.5
84.45 --- 84.5
87.45 --- 87.5
120.45 --- 120.4
123.45 --- 123.4
126.45 --- 126.4
129.45 --- 129.4
132.45 --- 132.4
135.45 --- 135.4
138.45 --- 138.4
141.45 --- 141.4
144.45 --- 144.4
147.45 --- 147.4
150.45 --- 150.4
153.45 --- 153.4
156.45 --- 156.4
159.45 --- 159.4
162.45 --- 162.4
165.45 --- 165.5
168.45 --- 168.5
171.45 --- 171.5
174.45 --- 174.5
177.45 --- 177.5
180.45 --- 180.5
183.45 --- 183.5
186.45 --- 186.5
189.45 --- 189.5
192.45 --- 192.5
195.45 --- 195.5
198.45 --- 198.5
201.45 --- 201.5
204.45 --- 204.5
207.45 --- 207.5
```

Comment: You can explicitly specify exactly what rounding you want by right clicking the field and using the Format options.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to determine what algorithm is currently being used.

Comment: The more I look at the numbers it seems randomized; as if crystal selects a group of numbers to round down in order to more closely hit the actual grouping total.

Comment: have you tried my suggestion?